# SHAP Kernel explainer for my pipeline model

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost, machine-learning-model, pipelines, shap

I am trying to use SHAP kernel explainer to understand my XGBOOST model. My data is the lending club data and I am trying to predict the Grade of each customer.

The data contains different types of data (Objects, float) so I use one hot encoding for object features and scaling for numerical features.

When I try to use the kernel explainer with the below code I get the following error.

```
    #creating training and validation sets
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, eh, test_size=0.2,random_state=777)
    #%%
    preprocess = make_column_transformer(((make_pipeline(IterativeImputer(initial_strategy='median',add_indicator=True,verbose=2,max_iter=100),StandardScaler())),numerical_features),((make_pipeline(SimpleImputer(strategy='constant',fill_value="Not Available",add_indicator=True),OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))),categorical_features))
grid_clf = make_pipeline(preprocess,RandomOverSampler(random_state=777),XGBClassifier(n_jobs=-1,verbosity=3,
 objective= 'multi:softprob',
 nthread=-1,
 scale_pos_weight=1,
 seed=27,tree_method='hist',n_estimators = 125,
                            max_depth = 15,
                            learning_rate = 0.2,
                            gamma = 0.24,
                            min_child_weight =6.0,
                            subsample = 0.8200000000000001,
                            colsample_bytree = 0.96))


clf=grid_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)



import shap
shap.initjs()

def model_predict(data_asarray):
    data_asframe =  pd.DataFrame(data_asarray, columns=X_test.columns)
    return grid_clf.predict_proba(data_asframe)
#%%

explainer = shap.KernelExplainer(model_predict,X_test2).shap_values(X_test2.sample(1))
```

The Error I get:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

How I can Solve this problem

Comment: From the error you get it's not clear that the error come frome the SHAP kernel. I suspect a mere format error. Does the model_predict(X_test2) works correctly ?

Comment: This line alone seems to be working:
explainer = shap.KernelExplainer(model_predict,X_test2)

Comment: Yes this line works and returns numpy array with probabilities for each class :
model_predict(X_test2)